# How to make the background color of a description label transparent?

Tags: tikz-cd

In the following `MWE`, the background color of `\cong` is constantly white. How can I make it transparent just like the remainder of the `tikz-cd` diagram?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\tcolorboxenvironment{defn}{enhanced jigsaw,colback={white!85!blue},boxrule=2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{defn}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[d, "" description]\\
        B\arrow[u, "\cong" {red,description}]
        \end{tikzcd}
        \end{equation}
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background color`. From the manual:

> `/tikz/commutative diagrams/background color=(color)`

> (no default, initially white)
> This key stores the name of a color, and is read by styles that fill the background, such as description and crossing over. It does not cause the background of diagrams to be filled.

You can apply the background color globally:

```
\tikzcdset{background color=none}
```

However, I don't think you want transparency here, as you arrows are passing through the description.

To apply locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\tcolorboxenvironment{defn}{enhanced jigsaw,colback={white!85!blue},boxrule=2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{defn}
        \begin{equation}
           \begin{tikzcd}[background color=white!85!blue]
              A \arrow[d, "" description]\\
              B\arrow[u, "\cong" {red,description}]
           \end{tikzcd}
        \end{equation}
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have many types of environments (featuring different colors) in my documents, so I have to change the background color for each one manually. Is that possible to totally remove the background of the diagram so that it can adapt itself to the color of its hosting environment?

Comment: Does it work if you define it as a new environment with color as an option?

Comment: I have all types of environments (definition, theorem, proposition, lemma, corollary, problem, example, etc.), and I also extensively use various colors in diagrams. So, adding option to environments makes a massive set of manual settings, as well.

Comment: I got you. Basically, you need to read the background dynamically and apply it to tikzcd. That's beyond my limited knowledge on this :)

Comment: I already appreciate your help. Maybe what I need is too complicated to be doable. So, if I received no other answer, I will definitely accept yours as the only way to go.